# how to run selenium rc test case in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-rc

My selenium RC java code is running successfully on firefox. Can anyone tell me how to run the same test case on internet explorer?

Comment: have you tried replacing `firefox` with `iexplore` in your command?

Answer (score 1):

Change the browser start command string you pass to DefaultSelenium factory. It will be *iehta or *iexplore depending on your selenium version.

```
new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Check out the docs for more info.

--Sai

Comment: Thanks but it is throwing Internet Explorer Script Error. It is saying 'No such interface supported'

Comment: Which version are you using.. It depends on that. I think the earlier versions supported *iehta.. Check the docs for that version for more info about browser interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `*firefox` with `*iexplore`. The exact code will vary depending on what language you're writing your test in or how you're actually launching the browser.

see: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#from-selenese-to-a-program and click the button for your particular language.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the Script error while running tests on IE with selenium RC, it might be because of not running the selenium server with Administrator privileges. I had the similar issue and could get it running with by running the selenium server as an Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Use "*iexplore" instead of "*firefox"

Answer (score 0):

In order to work the scripts on IE do the following steps

1.Navigate to ToolsInternet OptionsSecurityTrusted Sites

2.Click on “Sites” button and add the Urls of the application you are testing in “Add this website to the zone:” and clicking on “Add” button.

3.Navigate to ToolsInternet OptionsSecurity and disable the checkbox “Enable Protected Mode (requires restarting Internet Explorer)” and click on “Apply” and click “Ok”.

1. a. Navigate to ToolsInternet OptionsSecurity 
   b. Add all the URL’s of your application in the “Address of websites to allow” and click on “Add” button.
2. Navigate to ToolsInternet OptionsAdvanced options. Scroll down to the Security section, and select Allow active content to run in files on my computer. This will get rid of the pesky toolbar alert, and allow JavaScript to run automatically.